# Dialogue in First Person Fiction (Detective Mystery)

Tags: fiction, style, technique, dialogue, grammatical-person

Karl is my detective protagonist. His girlfriend, Jenna, is with him. He is hospitalized, and his boss, Rob Tucker, shows up for a visit. Which example of dialogue is correct? In true first person, can Rob and Jenna actually speak, or do I need to just say through Karl's eyes what they said?

Version 1:

> “Hey, buddy! Hi, Jenna. How’s our guy holding up?” It was my boss, Rob
>   Tucker. Jenna started to explain, “He’s doing pretty well, considering
>   what --"
>   “Rob!” I interjected, suddenly trembling with emotion, “There you are! What the hell happened partner? How did we --”
>   “Rob was hit, too, Karl,” Jenna said, and, as Tucker came fully into view,
>   I could see that his left arm was in a sling.
>   'Goddamn!' I thought. 'They got him, too!'
>   “It’s nothing,” replied Rob, sounding a little surly. “It’s just a scrape. It only took them a few minutes to fix me up. I’ll be fine in a couple of days.”

Version 2:

> As I lay there in bed - and in pain - my boss, Rob Tucker showed up in
>   the doorway and asked how I was doing.
>   Jenna started to explain, but I interrupted.
>   "Rob! It's you! What the hell happened, partner? How did we screw --"
>   Jenna then interrupted me to explain that Tucker had been hit, too.
>   Then I noticed that his left arm was in a sling. "God damn!" I blurted.
>   But Tucker brushed it off, saying it was nothing, and that he would be fine in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking whether in a story narrated in first person, you can have dialogue? Of course you can. Your MC is telling the story. Why shouldn't he tell the dialogue as is - the others' words as well as his own?

Here's an example for you, From the first chapter of Jim Butcher's *Storm Front* (the first book of the Dresden Files series).

> The new mailman, who looked like a basketball with arms and legs and a sunburned, balding head, was chuckling at the sign on the door glass. He glanced at me and hooked a thumb toward the sign. "You're kidding, right?"
>   I read the sign (people change it occasionally), and shook my head. "No, I'm serious. Can I have my mail, please."
>   "So, uh. Like parties, shows, stuff like that?" He looked past me, as though he expected to see a white tiger, or possibly some skimpily clad assistants prancing around my one-room office.
>   I sighed, not in the mood to get mocked again, and reached for the mail he held in his hand. "No, not like that. I don't do parties."
>   He held on to it, his head tilted curiously. "So what? Some kinda fortune-teller? Cards and crystal balls and things?"
>   "No," I told him. "I'm not a psychic." I tugged at the mail.
>   He held on to it. "What are you, then?"
>   "What's the sign on the door say?"
>   "It says 'Harry Dresden. Wizard.' "
>   "That's me," I confirmed.
>   "An actual wizard?" he asked, grinning, as though I should let him in on the joke. "Spells and potions? Demons and incantations? Subtle and quick to anger?"
>   "Not so subtle." I jerked the mail out of his hand and looked pointedly at his clipboard. "Can I sign for my mail please."

What you don't do in first person is tell what other characters are thinking (you can tell what your MC *thinks* they're thinking, but that's different). Also, nothing that goes on where your MC can't know about it - in another place, while they're sleeping etc. (The MC can hear about those events second-hand.)

Comment: Thank you. Galastel! I have been second-guessing myself for days! Your explanation below your example is VERY INFORMATIVE AND HELPFUL!